# Could we update the link to the supported prettify language codes?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, help-center, broken-link

I've hit this for a few times and it's quite misleading. If you go to the [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting), there's this quote; **please follow the link** (which I made bold in this quote):

> You can use either [**one of the supported prettify language codes**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify/81970#81970), like
>   `lang-cpp` or `lang-sql`, or you can specify a tag, and the syntax
>   highlighting language associated with this tag will be used:
>   ...

The problem is that this link targets [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify/81970#81970) where is written:

> **Available Language Hints Moved**
>
> Due to several lists of available hints existing throughout Meta, the entire list has been consolidated and moved to the following FAQ:
>
> [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work)

And even the link in this quote doesn't directly target a post where you could find a list of available languages. It links to the question (even when the user already knows what they're looking for).

So, could we update that markdown help link to target directly [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/179541)<sup>1</sup>?

---

<sup>1. Even if that answer actually repeats what's on that help page, at least there's the promised list of available lanaguge codes. A separate post listing only available codes would be better though (it would save the time needed for going through that long answer).</sup>

Comment: "While this link may answer the question..." and all that: any reason we don't just put the list in the help, maybe in a click-to-expand div?

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I assume it's because that list is difficult to edit, while a CW answer is simple to update as Google Prettify expands support, or as other edits to the text become necessary.

Comment: @ChrisHayes I was expecting the list to be automatically generated.  If it does require manual attention, fair enough.