# SO should automatically indent code

Tags: feature-request

When I post an answer / question and I wanted to include code, I always have to press space 4 times. And when I press ENTER, I have to press space 4 times *again*. That is just annoying. I really want SO can automatically press that space key four times for me, like in most IDEs.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299236/feedback-requested-code-editor-and-stack-snippets

Comment: Just paste it in, select it and hit Ctrl-K or the `{}` button.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Instead of indenting all your code manually, just type the code and then indent it later in a single step.

To do this, select the block that you want to indent. Then click on the "{}" icon above your post, or click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>. Then the whole selection is indented by 4 spaces, in one step.

The advantage of this is that you are in control. When you have an automatic indentation like you suggest, it may go off when you don't want it to. Or fail to go off when you *do* want it.

Comment: Seems they have done away with the formatting options (:angryface:). Ctrl+k no longer works either.

Comment: Not working... tried everything but SO is preventing me from publishing my code for some strange reason. At the least the line causing the error should be pointed out - we are completely clueless here