# Integrate a real time code syntax tester

Tags: feature-request, code, typographical-error

I wonder what your opinion is on the idea of integrating some kind of code syntax tester.

This would greatly help in preventing syntax errors when we write code for a specific question.

Comment: These annoying jsfiddle driven code blocks are already realized.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299236/feedback-requested-code-editor-and-stack-snippets?s=1|0.0000

Comment: hi πάντα ῥεῖ, thanks for your answer.. I talking about check most common languages syntax, that's for run demos only in html, js, css, but it's really good idea too, i vote up.

Answer (score 16):

I would really hope that questions and answers with code are

- syntax checked
- compiled
- debugged
- tested

*before* they turn up as a post on this site.

There are online services that can support with that effort like [ideone](http://ideone.com/) or [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) next to local installs of tool stacks. For JSfiddle a local replacement was created, called [Stack snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299236/feedback-requested-code-editor-and-stack-snippets).

Having scarce developer resources spend time on this doesn't feel like a good idea.

Comment: I am not taking about post, if you make a post you already checked your code, but when we write code for answer an specific question, i think that is more efficient have a little syntax checker

Comment: No, I don't think that is needed or wanted as it would encourage users to be sloppy on the quality of the answer because they rely on a feature that can't beat the real thing.

Comment: The OP can do the syntax checking and then fix any small typos etc. that have crept in as some contributor slaps in some code as an answer.  As long as the intent of the answer is there, why bother?

Answer (score 4):

There's no point to this.

Better tools already exist to check that your code is syntactically valid, ie, whatever compiler or runtime you're trying to feed your code to in the first place.

If somebody isn't going to use those tools, why would they bother using our lesser browser-based tools before asking their question?

The only situation where I can see this being used is when somebody isn't willing to take the time to understand the error messages being output by their compiler, and they want to dump their code on us to get a more human-friendly explanation. Such questions should be closed as having a simple typographical error.