# Add an optional field to link to source code repository when asking a question

Tags: feature-request, questions, asking-questions, external-links

I've run into situations where the original question did not include all the source code required to debug the program. Sometimes I've done this unwittingly, and to avoid this I find myself adding a link to my public GitHub repo.

Can we please have an optional field where noobs like myself can link to our public GitHub repos? This would make it much easier to find obscure bugs not covered by the code provided.

Comment: NOOOOOPE. MCVE is important, and M means "minimal". You should be able to isolate your problem more.

Comment: You can already link to github on your profile.  If you are talking about on a question or answer it should be able to stand on it's own (no link to code) to be complete.

Comment: *"obscure bugs not covered by code provided"* are **not** an appropriate thing to ask other people to find for you.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I meant unwittingly obscure. Sometimes the bug lies elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, and the process of making an MCVE should show that to you. We aren't here to do basic debugging for you.

Comment: @OP to be less condescending: Basically you shouldn't ask a question here without doing a LOT of research about it, Part of that research will be to isolate the issue or bug at hand. That research to isolate should leave you with a way smaller example. Most of the time, honestly, doing this WILL highlight the bug or issue. If it doesn't, you will be left with a better understanding of your issue, and a code sample that will make more sense to be posted here.

Comment: Related: [Is there a better way to upload minimal workable project code?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307322) [Is it OK to share files with Dropbox and other file sharing services in posts?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266714)

Comment: You already have the option of linking to a source code repository.

Answer (score 9):

No, adding field to link to source location does not promote creation of questions that up to SO standards.

Post, especially "debug my code" type of question must contain [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), links to complete source are optional and must not be needed to reproduce the problem.

If you need to post pages of code or link to complete project to reproduce the problem it is too early to ask question on SO. You may try to ask for debugging guidance, but it is unlikely to fit SO guidelines - searching for blogs/articles outside of SO will likely give you better chance to narrow problem down.

Answer (score 6):

No, just no. This goes against the principles of [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as outlined in [Alexei Levenkov's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334461/4751173).

Also, from the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (emphasis mine):

> include the code in your question itself. **Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.**

This is talking about cases where the OP provides a live demo (JSFiddle, SQLFiddle), but the argument is valid for external repositories as well.

In the rare case that potential answerers might want to look something up in your Github project, you can always insert the hyperlink yourself. The editor even has a button for this purpose.