# How can I upload a file to Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, code-formatting

I need to upload my code and put it in my question. How can I do that?

If there's no way to do so, then show me an alternative way (for example, a website I can upload my file and then use its link on Stack Overflow).

Comment: Read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120219/how-do-you-ask-a-question-on-stack-overflow) documentation it will help you to ask a good question with details

Comment: If your code is too large to fit in a question, then this site is likely the wrong place to put it. Please create a [mre]

Comment: Also see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question because it is primarily about whether SO supports file attachments, and only secondarily about formatting code as text. The two targets fail to ask or address the primary question here whatsoever, and thus are not accurate, let alone good, duplicate targets.

Comment: @TylerH The https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307322/is-there-a-better-way-to-upload-minimal-workable-project-code question is on point. The OP here is asking where to upload their code. That question is about how to upload their MRE. They're pretty much exactly the same. And rene's answer to it answers this question too; you can't upload files to this site. You can upload it to another site and provide a link, but the core code should be on this site.

Comment: @HereticMonkey This question serves much better as a more broad target given that it asks about files in general rather than just code, and has a much better answer. Frankly the question from 2015, while older, should be closed as a duplicate of this one, instead.

Comment: @TylerH "I need to upload my code" how does that ask about "files in general rather than just code"? I could see merging the two if all you want to do is get the answers together. This is a horrible question. Two sentences demanding a method for uploading their code?

Comment: @HereticMonkey "How can I upload a file to Stack Overflow?"

Answer (score 9):

Stack Overflow don't allow you to upload files as attachments to a question or answer. Instead, it asks for an MRE, or Minimal Reproducible Example.

You are required to debug your code (which is causing the error) and find just the specific section of the code that is making a problem (this is the "minimal" part of MRE). Make sure it is enough of the code that others can take that code and run it in their own environment and get the same outcome (this is the "reproducible" part of MRE).

Now copy that section of code and prepare to add it to your question. If that code is HTML, CSS, or JavaScript, then you can click this button to create a runnable "snippet" of code:

[image]

If the code is in any other programming language, then you can click this button, instead:

[image]

If your code uses or requires a *data set* in order to run or produce the necessary results, you are recommended to upload that data to a site like Pastebin or, if it's not text data, to a file-hosting site. Then you can link to the URL for your file upload in the post.

Note that you will be required to include your code before you can share a URL if you are new member. URLs without code are not allowed, and attempts to fake code content in order to post a URL may result in a question being negatively received.

Comment: I understand the part about not putting a whole file of **code**, but what about a file with some **data** ? Sometimes to run the OP's minimal example you need their input, typically looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66134354/how-to-join-range-of-a-splitline-in-python), OP had no choice but to upload an **image** of his data.

Comment: True, exceptions exist everywhere :)