# Format the word automatically if the cursor is on the word

Tags: feature-request, editor

Most of the times I find that I've to code-ify a word. My natural instinct having experience in word processors is to do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> with the cursor on the word.

But I'm met with "enter code here". This doesn't feel semantic. It would be great were it to apply backticks to the word on which lies the cursor.

I do know of double clicking a word and then adding the format, but what I am proposing is *easier* I guess.

I'd love to hear what you guys think of this.

Comment: That would conflict with http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299236/feedback-requested-code-editor-and-stack-snippets, which you might want to read (and possibly answer/comment).